# Multiple entries with same key: android:allowBackup=REPLACE and android1:allowBackup=REPLACE

Tags: android

I'm facing below using while compiling the project

Below are the error logs

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':sampleproject:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: android:allowBackup=REPLACE and android1:allowBackup=REPLACE
```

**AndroidManifest.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sample.mini" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.sample.toolkit.payment"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icn_app"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme"
        tools:replace="android:label, theme, allowBackup, android:icon,android:supportsRtl">


        <activity
            android:name="com.sample.SwiftActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.activities.TermsAndConditionActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme" />


    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 13):

Try removing the spaces from your `tools:replace` list.

`tools:replace="android:label,theme,allowBackup,android:icon,android:supportsRtl"`

This fixed the build error for me, but I'm still trying to figure out why entries after the space are ignored

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `android:` to the front of `allowBackup` in the `tools:replace` list

```
tools:replace="android:label,theme,android:allowBackup,android:icon,android:supportsRtl"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same failure notice:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Multiple entries with same key: android:supportsRtl=REPLACE and android:supportsRtl=REPLACE
```

android AndroidManifest.XML is:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:supportsRtl="false"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:supportsRtl"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:manageSpaceActivity=".ManageSpaceActivity">
```

finally I fixed it by add a space between "android:allowBackup," and "android:supportsRtl"

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup, android:supportsRtl"
```

I don't know why, but I think it may be Android Studio's bug, hope it will give you suggestions to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In My Case it was Happening Because i added PayuMoney Payment Gateway's PlugnPlay Dependency. After Removing it, i was able to build my App.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `android:` in each item

```
tools:replace="android:label, theme, allowBackup, android:icon,android:supportsRtl">
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error.

```
tools:replace="label,android:allowBackup,android:theme"
```

So I added **android:** in front of the label

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score -2):

Try my plugin to fix it.

[Seal - A gradle plugin to do precheck of Android Manifest.](https://github.com/2BAB/Seal)

**1.Compile&apply Seal plugin:**

```
// project's build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'me.xx2bab.gradle:seal-manifest-precheck-plugin:1.0.0'
    }
}

...

// app's build.gradle
apply plugin: 'seal'
```

**2.Configurations:**

```
def projectRoot = project.getRootProject().rootDir.absolutePath

// Folders may include AndroidManifest.xml files
// 1. For gradle plugin 2.3.0 or higher, build-cache is default choice,
// 2. But we should make sure snapshot-libs will be checked too.
// 3. Free to add your folders for more customization 
def manifestPath = [
        // for AAR of Release
        // see note below
        projectRoot + '/build-cache', 
        // for AAR of SNAPSHOT
        projectRoot + '/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar'
]

def removeAttrs = [
        'android:debuggable'
]

def replaceValues = [
        'android:allowBackup'
]


seal {
    enabled = true
    manifests = manifestPath

    appAttrs {
        enabled = true
        attrsShouldRemove = removeAttrs
    }

    appReplaceValues {
        enabled = true
        valuesShouldRemove = replaceValues
    }
}
```

**3.Note: If `build-cache` is enable, Seal recommends that custom build cache folder placed in the Project Folder.**

```
//gradle.properties
android.buildCacheDir=./build-cache
...
```

Comment: From my experience is better to find the change that suddenly broke a stable project and try to understand what the problem is. Adding this kind of iron bullets increase build times and can also hide real issues that fired the error.